# ServiceNow Email notification event query script

Tags: javascript, email, events, notifications, servicenow

I am using ServiceNow platform.

I have a requirement in email notification to show the latest work notes ONLY if the work notes have been updated.

Is it possible to query the events queue directly in the email notification and use that event to evaluate an if statement?

The mail script I have right now will display the latest work notes if there are work notes at all, but we just want display it when the work notes were updated only.

The notification is being triggered on the condition that either the additional comments were updated or the assignment group or assigned to changes. So I can't use a simple condition builder.

I also considered the technique in this post but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this in 2015, this post was back in 2011.

http://www.servicenowguru.com/scripting/business-rules-scripting/checking-modified-fields-script/

```
<mail_script>
var worknotes = current.work_notes.getJournalEntry(1);
if (worknotes !='') {
template.print("Latest Work Notes:");
template.print(current.work_notes.getJournalEntry(1));
}
</mail_script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling I might not understand the requirement completely, but it seems to me that you could just create a notification that triggers on the condition that the work notes are updated. Wouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: Well when the WorkNotes are updated, we only wanted to see those WorkNotes in the content of the notification. Our notifications also include the Additional Comments. So I couldn't use the condition builder but I did use the advanced condition as I have outlined in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a separate notification and using the advanced condition.

If the comments changes and work notes does not change the notification is sent. I created a separate notification with the same logic, except if the work notes changes and if the comments does not change then that one is sent.

The content of the email are set accordingly so we only see the latest change when it is updated as necessary.

```
var worknotesChanges = current.work_notes.changes();
  if (worknotesChanges) {
  answer = false;
  }
  else {
  answer = true;
  }
```